# How to count a particular character in QString Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

Imagine I have a QString containing this:

```
"#### some random text ### other info
a line break ## something else"
```

How would I find out how many hashes are in my QString?
In other words how can I get the number 9 out of this string?

---

## answer

Thanks to the answers, Solution was quite simple, overlooked that in the documentation
using the count() method, you can pass as argument what you're counting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#count-1) method and pass the `#` character:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    // Replace the QStringLiteral macro with QLatin1String if you are using Qt 4.

    QString myString = QStringLiteral("#### some random text ### other info\n \
                                       a line break ## something else");
    qDebug() << myString.count(QLatin1Char('#'));
    return 0;
}
```

Then with gcc for instance, you can the following command or something similar to see the result.

> g++ -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core -fPIC main109.cpp && ./a.out

Output will be: `9`

As you can see, there is no need for iterating through yourself as the Qt convenience method already does that for you using the internal [`qt_string_count`.](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp?id=08ee579cf025ad868bb405835b57d31e512b6fd6#n3649)

Comment: This is indeed right, I just don't see the difference between myString.count(QLatin1Char('#')) and myString.count("#")

Comment: With .count("#") you automatically convert your utf-8 string into latin1. With .count(QLatin1Char('#') you do it explicitly. Does not sound like a big difference, but your version won't work anymore when in your .pro file the  QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII variable is set. Why would anyone do this? Better control over your encoding. With automatic utf-8 -> latin1 conversion there can come some nasty and hard to find bugs into your program.

Answer (score 3):

Seems QString has useful counting methods.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#count-2

Or you could just loop over every character in the string and increment a variable when you find `#`.

```
unsigned int hCount(0);
for(QString::const_iterator itr(str.begin()); itr != str.end(); ++itr)
    if(*itr == '#') ++hCount;
```

---

**C++11**

```
unsigned int hCount{0}; for(const auto& c : str) if(c == '#') ++hCount;
```

Comment: @Vincent: I think it is not the right solution because this iterator is convoluted, and also the count-2 link provided is not the one needed in here. See my full working code below.